# Person-name was assumed to be unique, but now must differentiate

Tags: sql, normalization

A few months ago, some coworkers of mine received an xls containing the names (and other data) of the employees then working in the company we provided a SAS for. Amongst this list were two guys, who *miraculously* (or not) had the **exact** same name. I'm calling them *John Doe Woo*.

The first problem happened two weeks ago: Since both of them had (don't ask me how them or the HR people of their company didn't notice) the **same email** :  **jwoo@cpny.com**, and there are a few queries that  use the `distinct` clause in this particular fields, we had to call our client to *demand* that their emails were changed. In the end,  one of them ended up calling **jdoe@cpny.com**.

The second problem happened yesterday. We've noticed that we don't use the  `distinct` clause *only* for the email field, but also for the *name* field (in other queries). So,  given the facts that :
a) I can't change the queries without employing an enormous amount of time (and money, per se)
b) I can't change their names in any *visible* fashion at all
c) (consequence of a) ) : The only way to avoid the mistakes is by changing their names in 
the database
d) I **need** to change the names in any means.

What are my options?

Comment: Wow!  What a nice story illustrating the need for good database design, especially the use of synthetic keys for all tables.  In other words, you should probably spend the effort to redesign the database to use synthetic keys, fix the queries, and probably fix a bunch of other problems that have not yet appeared.

Comment: It's curious that anyone would expect a name to be unique, maybe it's because I only work with large databases that it sounds absurd.  You could add a constraint and demand that the person change their name.... or you could just fix the design.  Taking the time to do it right rather than finding a workaround will save you from many headaches down the road.

Comment: @GoatCO I think he was sarcastic.. he would probably not want to have to handle it.. but I know this situation - when you stuck with a previous design, which you cannot change, but you need to maintain... not fun, but the only way to do it is usually to do "ugly" things for it work...  I think he said that modifying the DB is not an option, therefore - he can only modify the data so the query will return the expected results.. if I did not understand the question correctly - fix me, so I could maybe suggest something better.

Comment: Why would it take a large amount of time and money to change a query? Surely then you should be rethinking the process to stream-line these changes. Otherwise you will just be adding more problems to the problem. @enenro options will work, but I agree with him that you have bigger problems that need fixing.

Comment: So, I wonder how this worked out?  Any updates?

Comment: Guys, thank you all so much for the feedback, it really enlightened the scenario here. Indeed, changing the DB structure seemed logical enough, but the problem is... We do not have **one** client, but many. And all of them uses the same database (Somewhere likely called as "multitenant", but I doubt it fits), so changing the structure would be equal to calling each one of them and awarding their patience with "Hi, sorry to bother you, but in the next few hours/days, we will be reprogramming our database, and your system will be off." ... Trust me, I'd really love **this** approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a space to the name, or use capital letters to distinct between the two...

I would go with capitalizations:
one would be "John Doe Woo" and the other "Joh doe Woo".
you can also use "-" "John-Doe Woo" and "john Doe Woo"...

But - it is clear that this is not what you should do,
you should fix the DB design..

Comment: Changing their names invisibly (as suggested in @Smandoli 's answer) ends up as being my best option for reasons I explained in a comment above. To ensure that the users won't see the difference, I inserted a space between their names - capitalization won't work, since the varchar are working with case-insensitive - and trimming each "word" within the name.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the data:  diffentiate the names.
2. Change the database: revise tables and/or queries
3. <strike>Change the data, but do it *invisibly*.</strike>

There is certainly a way to frame this up for management to decide.  I don't think you have a viable alternative to making that presentation.

***Edit:*** I presented the last option with Sarcasm Strike-though to indicate I don't consider it a good option.  Apparently it's the direction you actually went, so let me say I am glad you found a solution and wish you the best.

Comment: after reading your edit, I realized how ... little a single upvote is :D